# Putting pairs of files into separate zip archives

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have in a single folder pairs of files with the same filename and different extension.

ex.:

- filename1.txt
- filename1.docx
- filename2.txt
- filename2.docx
- filename3.txt
- filename3.docx
- filename4.txt
- filename4.docx
- etc...

I would like to select all those files and put the pairs in separate zip files.

ex.:

- filename1.zip (containing "filename1.txt" and "filename1.docx")
- filename2.zip (containing "filename2.txt" and "filename2.docx")
- filename3.zip (containing "filename3.txt" and "filename3.docx")
- filename4.zip (containing "filename4.txt" and "filename4.docx")
- filename5.zip (containing "filename5.txt" and "filename5.docx")
- etc...

Is that even possible using 7-zip command line and a prepared batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the `%` to `%%` for use in a batch file.

```
FOR %f in (*.txt) DO 7za a "%~nf.zip" "%~nf.txt" "%~nf.docx"
```